# How to run DB Unit test with Spring - Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, exception

I have Hsql DB and I want to run test on my Spring REST controller. I have that tags on my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:META-INF/webcore-servlet-test.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class}) //should I include this line, if you explain you are welcome
```

public class DeviceControllerTest {

```
@Autowired
private YService yService;
...
```

**EDIT:** Full stack trace as follows:

```
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@7215fb38] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void com.z.z.controller.DeviceControllerTest.testGetByName()] for test instance [com.z.z.controller.DeviceControllerTest@120540c]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:203)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBefores(SpringMethodRoadie.java:270)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:332)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'YController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.z.z.service.ZService com.z.z.controller.YController.ZService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Zservice': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.a.a.service.PersistenceService com.z.z.service.Impl.ZServiceImpl.persistenceService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:199)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.z.z.service.ZService com.z.z.controller.YController.ZService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Zservice': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.a.a.service.PersistenceService com.z.z.service.Impl.ZServiceImpl.persistenceService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Zservice': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.a.a.service.PersistenceService com.endersys.z.z.Impl.ZServiceImpl.persistenceService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.a.a.service.PersistenceService com.z.z.service.Impl.ZServiceImpl.persistenceService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceService': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:536)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    ... 64 more
```

**PS 1:** I changed original variable names so there maybe some incoherency.
**PS 2:** I read that:

> The TestContext framework does not instrument the manner in which a
>   test instance is instantiated. Thus the use of @Autowired for
>   constructors has no effect for test classes.

at: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html

Does it related to my problem?

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: The important part of the exception stacktrace is cut off.

Comment: @Ralph I added full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have a `entityManagerFactory` in your context. Add something like:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceXmlLocation="META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

On your question about the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`:

Annotating a transactional Spring test like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml" })
@Transactional
public class FoobarTest {
    // ...
}
```

is enough as rollback is true by default.

From the Spring reference on [`TransactionalTestExecutionListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx):

> In the TestContext framework, transactions are managed by the TransactionalTestExecutionListener, which is configured through the @TestExecutionListeners annotation by default, even if you do not explicitly declare @TestExecutionListeners on your test class.

Comment: @kamaci: you don't have a `entityManagerFactory`; I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Put your "test class" DeviceControllerTest into package, for example org.example.controller, with will be located in /src/test/java. In your folder /src/test/resources create package with same name, it mean org.example.controller and put there DeviceControllerTest-context.xml

DeviceControllerTest-context.xml file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:si="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!--{your application name}-local.properties - this properties will be taken for process your test. This properties located in /src/test/recources-->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*application-default.properties, classpath*:{your application name}-local.properties" />


    <bean class="{your class with you want use to @Autowired}[org.example.yService]" />
```

After all this manupulations your "test class" will look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class DeviceControllerTest {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(DeviceControllerTest .class);

    @Autowired
    private YService yService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //some actions TODO
    }
}
```

This structure is more "nicer", because you always know with context used for some specific "test" and your do not need to set location of your test class context inside "test class".